# What if a body Accelerate non-uniformly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

As we generally deals with *inertial frame of reference* and *non inertia frame of reference*, but what if a body is ***non-uniformly Accelerate***

**What do we do to make *newtons laws* still valid in** **later frame of Reference**

Comment: *So we cant apply pseudo force on particles.* Please explain why you think that.

Comment: Imagine a man in a merry go round that is spinning. There is a pseudo force acting on him in the reference frame of the merry go round. Lets say he had a kind of rocket booster attached behind him that is very faulty .He will experience a non uniform force because of it. Now, the total force is the sum of these two forces. One is uniform, other isn't. (I designed the booster to give a horizontal force, not vertical)

Comment: Can u elaborate